# How to give input to non-keras word embedding model from Keras model during training and get back output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow, nlp

I am trying to create a model using Keras which gives a input value to another non-keras word embedding model and get embedding of word back into this main keras model.

So, the problem is keras model run on graph and while giving input to non keras model, the value of input is of the form

```
Tensor("IteratorGetNext:9", shape=(None,), dtype=string)
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

But the word embedding model (Fasttext) only accept input in string format. So how to get the value of string in `Tensor("IteratorGetNext:9", shape=(None,), dtype=string)` and give it as input to Fasttext word embedding model and get output embedding and convert this output numpy embeddings back into tensor to be used into Keras model?

One way is to turn `run_eagerly = True` in `model.compile()` as it would give all values in numpy format instead of Tensor (running in eager mode instead of graph mode).

```
tf.Tensor([list of strings], shape=(batch_size,), dtype=string)
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>
```

But it would make model training time high.

Code :

```
class MovieModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    max_tokens = 10_000

    self.title_embedding = tf.keras.Sequential([
         tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
                vocabulary=unique_movie_titles,mask_token=None),
         tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(unique_movie_titles) + 1, 32)
    ])
    

  def call(self, inputs):
     return tf.concat([
          self.title_embedding(inputs["movie_title"]),
          #Word embeddings of "movie_title"
     ], axis=1)

  #Now I want to give "movie_title" as an input to FastText Model.             
   inputs["movie_title"] is a batch of movie titles. So I want to 
   process each string of this batch and split them into words and   
   call FastText Model to get embedding of every word and take 
   their average. And pass this averaged embedding along with
   self.title_embedding in def.call(). But as Keras train model on 
   Graph, I am not able to acccess the values of string in batch.
```

I can access the embeddings of word using `fasttext_model.wv[word]`
I am using [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/deep_recommenders) as reference to build my model.

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example?